# Paypal Authentication - unauthorized from SDK, Postman, etc

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We cannot authenticate to our live account after trying the SDK, REST, Postman, etc.  According to [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/postman/) I should be able to just change the client_id and client_secret in the forked postman project.  When I do so, and run "Generate Access Token" in Postman I get:

```
{
    "supported_authn_schemes": [
        "email_password",
        "remember_me"
    ],
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client Authentication failed"
}
```

I get similar 401 errors in the SDK.  I copied the client_id and client_secret from my account [here](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/edit) (clicking on live, and then the app to get them).

Is there some extra step we have to take to enable this?  We want to pull our own data to run custom royalty reports we have created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing credentials from sandbox to live, you also need to change your configuration to use the live endpoints.

Live credentials will not work with sandbox endpoints, nor vice-versa; the two environments are completely separate

If it still does not work when everything seems correct, create a new REST app and try its credentials.

Comment: Thank you.  I have changed the base_url to https://api-m.paypal.com and also https://api.paypal.com (both seem possible per https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/urls/ ).  The end point I am trying to hit is {{base_url}}/v1/oauth2/token.  I get the same error for either base_url.  Is there something else I need to change for the live endpoints?  Thanks again.

Comment: No, those URLs (without `sandbox.`) and a valid live client-id and secret is all you need. Try a new REST app

Comment: Creating a new app worked.  I don't know why the client_ID and client_secret from the first one did not work. Thanks!